# How to generate the mentioned symbol using keyboard? Didn't find anything helpful on the internet. Thank you

Tags: html, unicode

[image]

Is there any way to generate symbol shown in picture by using keyboard combinations. Searched a lot on the internet but didn't find anything suitable.

Comment: You messed up with the picture. Can you please try again? Also, I'm not sure StackOverflow is the correct forum for this question.

Comment: Ok, now I see the picture, but I'm still not sure stackoverflow is the correct forum for this. Also, what operating system?

Comment: The symbol is there now. It is actually a concatenation of '>' and '|'. Operating system is Windows. I want it for my website for pagination functionality. Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for this `⇥`? Looks similar to yours. You can find many more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_arrows.asp).

Comment: @Eric I am afraid that's a tad different.

Comment: Be carefull with this. If it's to be used in a web page you are assuming that the font in the user agent will have that character/icon. For those things it's generally better to use something like fontawesome http://fontawesome.io/icons/#video-player

Comment: @Tarun : See I've added the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Unicode Character to combine '>' and '|'.

```html
<div>
&#12297;&#10072
</div>
```

Comment: Naah ... It is giving me something  〉❘

Answer (score 0):

This is the **Latin** **Small Letter Turned K** character.

Print in html as : ʞ ( `&#670;`)

```html
Latin Small Letter Turned K :   &#670;
```

See the doc below for the all type of character codes like utf-8, utf-16 etc.
See the HTML entity code in the following doc.
https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+029E